# Open source RSS parser

Tags: .net, open-source, rss

Before rolling my own RSS parser, is there a really good open-source parser already written for C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like the [RSS.NET](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rss-net/) library is worth a try. It does seem to be reasonably complete.
And judging by the [code examples](http://www.rssdotnet.com/documents/code_examples.html), it seems very easy to use.

**Edit:** I was looking for this earlier but couldn't find it for some reason... RSS syndication is now in fact built into the .NET Framework 3.5 as part of WCF. See [this MSDN magazine article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135976.aspx) for an introduction (scroll down for the section about the syndication API). Also see the answer to [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576267/c-rss-reader).

Comment: RSS.NET isn't open source any longer :(. It really seems like a great product.

Comment: Yeah, didn't realise that. Quite unfortunate...

Comment: See the update to my post. It seems like you have a solution existing in the .NET Framework 3.5. :)

Answer (score 2):

There's one called [Argotic Syndication Framework](http://www.codeplex.com/Argotic)

If I were to roll my own, I would probably use this one as a reference.

Answer (score 1):

I recently used [FeedDotNet](http://feeddotnet.codeplex.com/) from codeplex.  It was very simple to use, took very little time to get working.