# RSS Parser for .NET

Tags: .net, asp.net, rss, parsing

Any recommendations for RSS parser library in .NET?

Comment: What version of .NET are you coding for?

Answer (score 4):

Several questions out there already that might be helpful. Look at [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=.net+rss).

Perhaps some of these might be helpful:

- [RSS library in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510575/rss-library-in-net)
- [RSS parser in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684507/rss-parser-in-net)
- [Open Source RSS Parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669518/open-source-rss-parser)
- [The best .Net library to handle feeds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87278/what-is-the-best-net-library-to-handle-feeds-atomrss)

Answer (score 2):

[SyndicationFeed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed.aspx) is a part of .NET framework, you can find this class in System.ServiceModel.dll assembly.

You can read and created RSS feeds using SyndiacationFeed and [System.ServiceModel.Syndication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.aspx) namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [rss.net](http://www.rssdotnet.com/) which works fine.

Answer (score 0):

[rssdotnet](http://www.rssdotnet.com) works the best and is open source