# rss parser in .net

Tags: c#, .net, rss

what's the best RSS reader for .net out there? most efficient and easy to use
the ones i found are really complicated

Comment: Are you trying to write your own? Isn't RSS an xml format?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135976.aspx

.net has a class to parse ATOM and RSS feeds. Check out the links. What are you trying to do? Can you give more information?

Alternatively You can just remove the "Feed version" from the XML file and parse it as a normal XML file using xmlDocument class.

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at the [System.ServiceModel.Syndication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.aspx) namespace in .NET 3.5?

There are other answers on Stack Overflow that may help - for example: [C# RSS Reader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576267/c-rss-reader).

Comment: Simon, thanks! Have also been looking for a thing like this! I had no idea this was in 3.5!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at Argotic too - http://www.codeplex.com/Argotic

I have used Argotic during .Net 1.1 when the Syndication framework was not available in the framework and it did the job.

However, I would recommend the use of System.ServiceModel.Syndication if it does everything you need.