# Stable RSS reader using .NET

Tags: .net, rss, atom-feed

I have been looking for a stable RSS/Atom library for .NET, preferably open source like AS3 Syndication Library created by Adobe.

I want to integrate an RSS feed in my .NET based site.

Also, are there any JavaScript libraries for the same RSS feed reader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answered a similar question some time back : net has a class to parse ATOM and RSS feeds. Check out the links.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135976.aspx

Alternatively You can just remove the "Feed version" from the XML file and parse it as a normal XML file using xmlDocument class.

[rss parser in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684507/rss-parser-in-net/684518#684518)

Comment: Is parsing the feed client slide better than on server side?
same thing can be done using javascript?

Also found this 
http://www.codeplex.com/ASPNETRSSToolkit

Comment: The syndication readers may be stable but the are not very robust, one little bit of wrong formatting and the entire feed fails to read.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the [System.ServiceModel.Syndication Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.aspx) can be of help?

Answer (score 1):

This seems a no-brainer.

Argotic (http://exist.sourceforge.net/atompub.html)  is a mature, stable, open source .Net library for RSS and Atom. I've worked within the sources, and they're very feature complete and sensibly implemented (including support for Atom extensions such as  GeoCoding, Dublin Core, iTunes and trackback).