# Rss library in .NET

Tags: .net, xml, rss

Is there a RSS library for .NET?

Comment: What specific functionality do you need?

Comment: @jefclaes - consider qualifying your question with a .net version. .NET 3.5 includes RSS/ATOM support out of the box.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might start with the [System.ServiceModel.Syndication Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.aspx).  It includes classes for RSS and Atom.

Comment: +1.  This requires .Net 3.5, but it works great.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Google](http://www.google.nl/search?q=rss+library+.net), there are a few options:

- [RSS.NET](http://www.rssdotnet.com/) - with an updated version [over here](http://www.web20tools.net/)
- [FeedDotNet](http://www.codeplex.com/FeedDotNet/)

Also, many commercial networking toolkits for .NET (e.g. /n Software's [IP*Works!](http://nsoftware.com/portal/dotnet/)) support RSS.

In addition to that, the [RSS protocol](http://www.rssboard.org/rss-specification) itself isn't too involved: using .NET's native [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f3wxbf3f%28VS.80%29.aspx) and some LINQ to XML magic, it [should not be too difficult](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/07/using-linq-to-xml-and-how-to-build-a-custom-rss-feed-reader-with-it.aspx) to implement a RSS client yourself...

Answer (score 1):

I have answered a similar question 2 times ;- ) Check this out : [rss parser in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684507/rss-parser-in-net/684518#684518)

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.aspx
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135976.aspx
>
> .net has a class to parse ATOM and RSS
>   feeds. Check out the links. What are
>   you trying to do? Can you give more
>   information?
>
> Alternatively You can just remove the
>   "Feed version" from the XML file and
>   parse it as a normal XML file using
>   xmlDocument class.

Answer (score 0):

There are tons, including using LinqToXML, however, IMHO, the Argotic framework is the most robust.

[http://argotic.codeplex.com/](https://web.archive.org/web/20180116000209/http://argotic.codeplex.com:80/)

Answer (score -1):

There are many of them, e.g. [rss.net](https://www.rssdotnet.com/).

And it's easy to [implement reading](https://web.archive.org/web/20141028165943/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/willemf/archive/2005/10/30/58562.aspx) without any lib