# Web scraping (HTML format of popular websites)

Tags: rss, screen-scraping

How do I scrape any website for creating a feed for my website? What format do most popular sites follow?

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to reverse-engineer each website, because they don't follow a common format or something (freedom of the web developer). What about just scraping *their* rss feeds?

Comment: how do i access a RSS feed for a youtube link for example?

Comment: @Sussagittikasusa what do you mean exactly?

Comment: I want something like facebook does when you enter a link into its status bar and it loads a snapshot of the web page?

Comment: @Sussagittikasusa That's something totally different. What a snapshot?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [Octoparse(A free web scraper)](http://www.octoparse.com/) to deliver timely information to end users.

I use it to scrape data from multiple data sources and convert the extracted data into structured tables of data. It’s easy to automatically deliver enormous timely information to all the users who have subscribed to your data feed. 
You just schedule an extraction task in Octoparse to collect web data automatically and enrich your applications with up-to-date Internet content.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe many sites scrape for content, but if you wish to, I would go with RSS (Really Simple Syndication). Almost every website will have one, and the scraping from that is easy.
[RSS 2.0 Specification](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html)

[Brian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576267/c-rss-reader/576275#576275) makes a nice post on a few ways to read RSS (in C#).

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943474.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943480.aspx

[Here](http://www.cottonrohrscheib.com/blog/2009/03/09/combine-multiple-rss-feeds-into-one/BlockquoteBlockquote) are some web-based tools as well to make a single feed from combining multiple others.

Quoted the list here:

> 

1. RSS Mixer
2. FeedBlendr
3. FeedTwister
4. BlogSieve
5. RSSMesh
6. RSS Mix
7. BlastFeed
8. Feed Combine
9. FrankenFeed
10. Yahoo Pipes

Hope this helps :)

Comment: So what does facebook basically do when you enter a link into its status bar and it loads a snapshot of the web page?

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize you were going for a facebook type thing. From what I can tell (no references), Facebook just tries to get the page name (which, for this page is in html as :<title>Web scraping (HTML format of popular websites) - Stack Overflow</title>), all the main images (if you are in firefox try rightclick-view page info-media), and also and <h1> and/or<h2> <h3> tagged names.