# create RSS reader in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, rss-reader

I use VS2010, C# I want to read RSS content from other sites and display them in my site, currently this process is performed manually (site admin searches other sites and copy/pastes related content in news items!), but I want to do it automatically and I think the best solution is RSS, I've tried several sample codes but none of them worked, is there an easy way to implement RSS reader in ASP.NET? what are my options here?

Comment: have you looked at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576267/c-sharp-rss-reader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Read RSS Link

```
public void ReadDoc(XmlDocument rssDoc)
{
    XmlNode nodeRss = null;
    XmlNode nodeChannel = null;
    XmlNode nodeItem = null;
    try
    {
        if (rssDoc == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Loop for the <rss> tag
        for (int i = 0; i < rssDoc.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
        {
            // If it is the rss tag
            if (rssDoc.ChildNodes[i].Name == "rss")
            {
                 nodeRss = rssDoc.ChildNodes[i];
                 break;
            }
        }

        if (nodeRss == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeRss.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
        {
            if (nodeRss.ChildNodes[i].Name == "channel")
            {
                nodeChannel = nodeRss.ChildNodes[i];
                break;
            }
        }

        if (nodeChannel == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Loop for the <title>, <link>, <description> and all the other tags
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeChannel.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
        {
            if (nodeChannel.ChildNodes[i].Name == "item")
            {
                nodeItem = nodeChannel.ChildNodes[i];
                if (nodeItem["title"] != null){}
                if (nodeItem["description"] != null){}
                if (nodeItem["pubDate"] != null){}
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        nodeRss = null;
        nodeChannel = null;
        nodeItem = null;
    }
}
```

---

```
public void CreateRSS(String Path)
{
    XmlDocument doc = null;
    XmlTextReader rssReader = null;
    Label doclbl = null;
    Label snolbl = null;
    try
    {
        try
        {
            rssReader = new XmlTextReader(Path);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (rssReader == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        doc = new XmlDocument();
        try
        {
            doc.Load(rssReader);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (doc == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        ReadDoc(doc);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        doc = null;
        rssReader = null;
        doclbl = null;
        snolbl = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Apparently you do not understand what this code do, and what the question ask.